# Historical data usage of a table in MSSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, diskspace

I'm a beginner in SQL and I executed the below Stored Procedure in MSSQL to get the disc space related stuff for a table. This one is giving the current status of this table. If I run the same tomorrow, It gives me the similar stuff and We can insert this into a table for the regular monitoring.

```
EXEC sp_spaceused '[dbo].[TableName]'
```

But I'm looking for the same data from last one year to see how this table is growing by each month, May be I want to extend it to all tables in my DB.

I tried running this Stored Procedure regularly, it is going to help for future statistics, but not for historical.

Comment: SQL Server does not maintain historical table statistics, this is down to you to track as you have already noted.

Comment: I am just curious whether any of the sys tables holds this information or not

Comment: I am just curious when we add the new data to any db table, whether it saves some where in tables, how many records are added to table and how much space is consumed everytime

Comment: all transactional data are reflected in logs

Answer (score 0):

the subject is extensively discussed in the following post [DB Admin - Which table is causing the hike](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/102828/how-can-i-determine-which-tables-are-causing-the-database-to-grow-over-time)

hope this helps
NR